# Can someone prove or help me understand the following about Euclidean fields?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Why is it that if $\delta$ and $\delta'$ both divide $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and that every $\gamma$ which divides $\alpha$ and $\beta$ also divides $\delta$ and $\delta'$, then $\delta$ and $\delta'$ are associates?

Comment: Can you give an example of $\delta$ and $\delta'$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or a Euclidean field of your choosing? Just so everyone's on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Well if $\delta$ and $\delta'$ both divide $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $\delta$ divides $\delta'$ and $\delta'$ divides $\delta$.